# How to properly configure QML import path in a C++ defined QML module in a cmake project?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml, qt-creator

Im adding cmake support to the cutehacks duperagent library (http client library), and everything seems to be working just fine, except the QtCreator Qml module import path. The qml engine is capable of importing the module because the unit test runs, but im unable make QtCreator to recognize it.
This is the the fork with the cmake support https://github.com/ecruzolivera/duperagent

Can someone please help me with this?

Regards,
Ernesto

[image: import path error]

Comment: The simplest way is to create a new project in QtCreator and select `CMake` as a build system. The `CMakeLists.txt` file will be created automatically with all the settings you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but that dont seem to be working in this case.

Comment: In my project I have created some cmake custom commands to copy my (styles) library to the QT_DIR. But I'd say it should be possible to run QtCreator with the QML2_IMPORT_PATH set to the build folder with your library (but you have to be precise with the folder structure and qmldir stuff)